# Make items equal

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of numbers, find the minimum operation required to make them equal.

We have some rules to perform operations to make array items equal.

Let's say we are doing m number of operations from 1 to m.

If the operation is an odd one like 1, 3, 5 etc then pick an item from array and add 1
If the operation is an even one like 2,4,6 etc then pick an item from array and add 2
We need not do an operation also

**Example: A = [1,2,4]**

```
operation 1, odd, select 1st item add 1 , A= [2,2,4]
operation 2, even, select 1st item add 2, A = [4,2,4]
operation 3, odd, do nothing
operation 4, even, select 2nd item add 2, A = [4,4,4]
```

**Result : 4**

This is my approach :

```
public long solve(int[] arr) {
    int max = Arrays.max(arr);
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int e : arr) {
        if(max - e >0) list.add(max - e);
    }

    Collections.sort(list);
    int n = list.size();
    long result = 0;
    for(int i=0, j=n-1, k=1; i <=j; k++) {
        if(k%2==1) {// odd
            int e = list.get(i);
            e--;
            list.set(i, e);
            if(e <=0) i++;
        } else {// even
            int e = list.get(j);
            e -= 2;
            list.set(j, e);
            if(e <=0) j--;
        }
       result++;    
    }
}
```

Problem with my code, it takes more time to run so not time efficient.
Also I am assuming all big numbers will be at end of difference list and small numbers at beginning, so I am reducing 1 at beginning and reducing by 2 in the end, this logic also has bug because after few iterations the end item can be smaller than beginning item.

How to solve this problem in less time.

Comment: Hint. if you need `x` +1s and `y` +2s, you can complete in `min(2*x-1, 2*y)`. You cannot substitute a +2 for a +1, but you can substitute 2 +1s for a +2. And your list will need to wind up either at `max(arr)` or `max(arr) + 1`.

Comment: Seems the goal is to make all elements equal to the largest (call it `m`). For each element `e` get the difference `d(e)=m-e` (store in an array). You add 1 or 2, each pair adds 3. Step 1, round down for `d(e)/3` and sum, that's the number of pairs you can do for each (multiply by 2). Subtract from each `d(e)`to get 0, 1, or 2. 0 are done, count numbers of 1 or 2. If they're the same, they can also be done in pairs, multiply by 2 and add. If different, take the difference - those also need two steps so double and add. More 1s mean the last step can be skipped, so subtract 1 then.

Comment: @JohnBayko With `[4, 4, 4, 4, 5]` you can make them all `5` in 7 steps and all `6` in 6 steps. So the max is not always fastest.

Comment: @btilly I see. I suppose you could use the same algorithm I outlined twice, one for each. But I haven't checked that it actually works, it's kind of a first draft.

Comment: This problem is only interesting if one can prove that a particular algorithm produces an optimal solution. If such an algorithm can be identified I expect implementing it in code would be straightforward.

Comment: @btilly `if you need x +1s and y +2s, you can complete`, in this case I will have only `x+y` operations right. Then what this `min(2*x-1, 2*y)` indicates?

Comment: @learner It indicates the number of operations that you need before getting `x` +1s and `y` +2s available to use.

Answer (score 0):

An optimal solution can be obtained by modelling the problem as in [integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) with binary-valued variables (zero or one).

First observe that a lower bound on the minimum number of operations required can be easily obtained by permitting 1 or 2 to be added to one of the elements of the array during each operation, even or odd.<sup>1</sup> Let that value be `ops`. We begin by attempting to find a solution that requires `ops` operations. If one is found it must be optimal, so we are finished; else we increment `ops` by one and try again, and keep trying until we find a feasible solution, which must be optimal. Operation are denoted below by `i`, `1 <= i <= ops`.

---

Linear programs have:

- variables;
- an "objective function", which is a linear combination of the variables that is to be maximized or minimized; and
- linear constraints, which are linear combinations of the variables that must not greater than, or be equal to, a specified number (not greater than or equal to being specified in the formulation).

In linear programming some of the constraints require the variables to be non-negative. In integer programming some or all of the variables are in addition restricted to equalling integer values. The present model is a special case of integer programming where all the variables must equal zero or one.

Integer programs are solved with free or commercial integer programming "packages". Note that it generally takes much more time to solve an integer program than a linear program of similar size. In fact, some integer programs cannot be solved in a lifetime, whereas a linear program with similar numbers of variables and constraints might be solved in milliseconds.

---

Let the given array (whose elements are to be made equal) be `a`, with `n` elements, where the j<sup>th</sup> element (base one) equals a<sub>j</sub>.

---

The variables are as follows:

- x1<sub>ij</sub> equals 1 if 1 is added to a<sub>j</sub> at odd operation i; else equals 0;
- x2<sub>ij</sub> equals 1 if 2 is added to a<sub>j</sub> at even operation i; else equals 0; and
- x0<sub>i</sub> equals 1 if nothing is done at operation i; else equals 0.

---

The objective function is arbitrary as we are merely looking for a feasible solution. It could be, for example:

min 0 * x1<sub>11</sub>

---

The constraints are as follows.

*For each odd operation `i` and each array element `j`:*

a<sub>j</sub> = a<sub>j</sub> + x1<sub>ij</sub>

Σ<sub>j</sub>x1<sub>ij</sub> <= 1

x1<sub>ij</sub> equals 0 or 1

*For each even operation `i` and each array element `j`:*

a<sub>j</sub> = a<sub>j</sub> + 2 * x2<sub>ij</sub>

Σ<sub>j</sub>x2<sub>ij</sub> <= 1

x2<sub>ij</sub> equals 0 or 1

*For each j, 1 <= j < ops*

a<sub>j</sub> - a<sub>j+1</sub> = 0

---

Notice that Σ<sub>j</sub>x1<sub>ij</sub> <= 1 (for example) requires that  x1<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for exactly one j, and x1<sub>ij</sub> = 0 for all other j, or x1<sub>ij</sub> = 0 for all j (the latter meaning nothing happens at operation i).

<sup>1</sup> Add 2's then if necessary one 1 to each element to make it equals the largest value. Then increase the largest value by one and repeat. The one with the fewer operations provides a lower bound on the optimum.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
find the largest number, max, in array
for each number in array
    number = number + (max - number)
```

thus

```
public int[] makeEqual(int[] arr) {
   int max = arr[0];
   for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
       if( arr[i] > max ) {
          max = arr[i];
       }
   }
   for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       arr[i] += (max - arr[i]);
   }
   return arr;
}
```

Comment: This misses the point of the question. They have a limited set of operations and just assigning an element is not one of the operations.